# Toggle Notification Bar programmatically Android

Tags: android, notifications

I want to pull down notification bar if it is not and if it is already down then want to close it programmatically.
I tried `performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS);`

But is only bring down the notification bar does not close it.
but I want to toggle it.
I know it is possible because there are some apps that are doing this.